# How to remote access my router.?

Tags: networking, remote-access

I have an Asus rt n10+ router and I flashed dd-wrt in it.

My remote access is still not working?

I tried a lot of options researching forums here there and everywhere.

And why is my public IP different from the WAN IP my router says? And what IP should I use to access my router remotely? The public IP found on whatismyip.com and any other sites that do that or the WAN IP my router says

My WAN IP is 192.168.x.x

My public IP is 121.54.x.x

When I try to access it by using my routers WAN IP through 8080 it connects through my computer, but when i try it remotely it doesn't.

And even if i try my public IP on port 8080 it doesn't work, even though I am connected to the router via LAN.

I don't understand why this is. I am using my iPhone's connection to access it

[image]

Comment: I would also recommend turning on HTTPS for your Web GUI... Unless you're hosting an SSL enabled webserver...

Comment: Why is hosting an SSL enabled webserver an exception? Can't the connection handle both?

Answer (score 2):

I am reading your setup in two possible ways: First of all the classic setup

[image: Picure with the OPs network]

This picture has your LAN network in the 192.168.1.0/24 range and uses 121.54.x.x for your public WAN IP.

> When I try to access it by using my routers WAN IP through 8080 it connects through
>   my computer, but when i try it remotely it doesn't.

When on your LAN your devices should connect to the router via 192.168.1.1:8080.

This should work for all devices on the LAN. Regardless if they are wired (as the desktop and the server in the picture) or wireless (e.g. laptop, iPhone using wireless). Some routers have an option which forbids wireless access even from inside the LAN.

You usually can not connect to the router from the inside using the outside IP.
Read: Trying to connect to the router using 121.54.x.x:8080 should not work from the devices with a green IP.

The opposite is try when you try to to connect from the outside (the WAN side) of your router. In that case you approach from 'the red side' and you need to use 121.54.x.x:8080.

You should be able to test this via any normal computer on the Internet. E.g. a server at a university, some random PC at work, and maybe even from your iPhone using GPRS or its successors.

Caveeat: Many mobile networks use an extrea layer of NATting and this may interfere. Mobile phones and thus not a good object to test with.

---

Alternatve, you used the right description and actually have 192.168.x.x. as WAN, then you have the situation as below:

[image: WAN 192.168 just in case]

> Why is my public IP different from the WAN IP my router says?

Your provider may use an extra layer of NATting. Or maybe the ISP is using a webproxy and whatismyip.com answers with the IP of the proxy?

> I don't understand why this is. I am using my iPhone's connection to access it

How are you using your phone? via Wireless (LAN) or via GPRS/G3/G4/whatever ?

What are your LAN ip ranges? Are they actually different from the IPs used on the WAN?

Is you Asus router you only device and does it plug directly into the ethernet jack of your fibre/DSL-modem? Is that a normal modem or a complex device which also tries to do NAT? In that case the second router might actually be in your home rather than at your ISP. (or worst case, you might be doing an extra NAT layer at home and the ISP may be doing that).

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question literally it sounds like you are trying to access the router remotely via your private ip address..192.168.x.x. This address can only be used internally and many routers dont support access via the WAN address from inside your network.

WAN ip and public ip are the same thing albeit different terminology.

So when you are logging in remotely outside your network use the address of your WAN ip...in your case the 121.54 number making sure to append the 8080

Answer (score 1):

Your modem is set to NAT mode, where you really want BRIDGED mode.  This is shown by you having a 192.168.x.x address on your WAN.

Look at your WAN gateway, then open that address in a browser.  You may have to change the subnet of your router if it's the same on both sides (WAN/LAN).   If WAN is 192.168.1.x, change your router to serve 192.168.2.x, that way you can connect to the modem's 192.168.1.1 (typically) address.

No idea how to change modes (NAT/BRIDGED) on modem since you didn't specify.  But have a look, often there's an admin/user code on bottom of modem (typically DSL modems) which can be used to log in and adjust settings.

Answer (score -2):

Not all routers can be access remotely. Though router has its own feature to enable web access, to other router brands it takes no effect even though you enabled the web access.

Comment: He is using the ddwrt firmware!